# SQL Server 2000 LEN function only return length up to first occurrence of carriage return/linefeed

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

The problem I have is that the length of a `varchar` is not returned correctly if the value contains `CR/LF` values (Not trailing).

For example the following query snippet:

Data is something like:

```
<xml><name>Name[CR/LF] Name</name></xml>
```

The query like:

```
DECLARE @myid as INT
DECLARE @xmldata as VARCHAR(8000)
SET @myid = 1
SELECT @xmldata = xmldata FROM mytable WHERE id=@myid

PRINT 'The length is ' + CAST(LEN(@xmldata) AS VARCHAR(6))
PRINT 'Data:'
PRINT @xmldata
```

Will output:

```
The length is 15
Data:
<xml><name>Name[CR/LF] Name</name></xml>
```

I would expect the LEN function to return 35 as the length?

This is on SQL Server 2000 SP4 (8.00.2065)

Does anyone know if there is a setting or another function to use to prevent this.
One option I can think of is remove the carriage return and linefeed character in the select:

```
SELECT @xmldata = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(xmldata, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(10) + CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

but was hoping that there is maybe another function or setting to override the behaviour.

Comment: What does `DataLength()` return?

Comment: Is `[CR/LF]` in your example data literal or is that where a newline goes?  I ask because you've actually used multiple lines to represent the data.

Comment: Can you post actual repro code? I suspect what you've posted is somewhat fudged, since `@xml_value` only appears in the final line, and was never set - do you actually have two different variables in your real code (`@xmldata` and `@xml_value`)?

Comment: @Tim, yes the `[CR/LF]` is where the newline goes, the editor auto incremented the xml.

Comment: Strict company rules prohibit posting code :(.

Comment: The @xml_value should be xml_value, thank will fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns 35 (not 33) twice in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
DECLARE @xmldata as VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @xmldata = '<xml><name>Name' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' Name</name></xml>'
--                 000000000111111         1          1      112222222222333333
--                 123456789012345         6          7      890123456789012345
PRINT LEN(@xmldata)
print DataLength(@xmldata)
PRINT @xmldata
```

It looks right to me.

Comment: In 2005, I can't repo this either, only seeing this in SQL2000, will try with datalength() today and report back later